# CodeIgniter ajax dynamic forms

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, url

I'm actually trying to do a dynamic administration about teams in my project. It means for example, the user has 3 buttons. Each buttons calls a function from a controller that displays a form.

However, when the form appears, the url is wierd when i press submit.

```
function ajax_get(){

var uri_segment = "<?=$this->uri->segment(3);?>";

$('#editTeam').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        async : false,
        url : "<?=base_url().'ajax/team/get_editTeam/';?>"+uri_segment,
        dataType : "html",
        success : function(data){
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                $('#divPage').html(data);
            }, 300);

        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

This function display a view in a div, and then i have a form

```
function ajax_editTeam()
{
$('form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        async : false,
        url : "www.google.fr",
        data : $(this).serializeArray(),
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function(data)
        {

        }
    });


    return false;
});
 }
```

For this form I have another ajax call that save the field and update the team informations. As you can see I wrote 'www.google.fr' as url but it changes nothing

When I submit the form, I have a wierd url in firebug.

**This is the console from firebug :**
GET http://fresh-league.com/ajax/team/get_editTeam/30 200 OK 164ms
POST http://fresh-league.com/ajax/team/editTeamget_editTeam 404 Not Found 354ms

Can you please tell me why I have another requested url than www.google.fr ?

Thanks for answers
Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of [Same Origin Policy](http://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy) restrictions on the browser.

Same Origin Policy restrict browsers from making ajax request to a domain other than form which the source script was downloaded.

There are multiple ways to overcome this

1. Use [jsonp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)
   If the requesting resource supports jsonp then you can use it, jquery has [built in support](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/#jsonp) for jsonp. for using jsonp you need to pass a request parameter `callback=?` and set the datatype as `jsonp` or use [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/#jsonp) to request a json resource.
2. Use [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/)

Answer (score 0):

You have the answer in your question,

this is correct: `url : "<?=base_url().'ajax/team/get_editTeam/';?>"+uri_segment`

and this isn't: `url : "www.google.fr"` because you are not calling any function from your controller, 
try giving it a url like the first ajax call.

Comment: Hi

The www.google.fr was an example, I think i would have another type of error in my console, like 401 unauthorized.

I don't understand why the url parameter in the second request isn't 'read' by jquery

I always have this url : http://fresh-league.com/ajax/team/editTeamget_editTeam instead of 

http://fresh-league.com/ajax/team/edit/30